# How to truncate text in a column in Tansack React Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend, material-table

I am using Transact React table, and I want to truncate text after 3 letters in one column, lets suppose the First Name column in the below image. How to achieve that?? Where to make changes

[image]

```
      <EnhancedTable
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        setData={setData}
        updateMyData={updateMyData}
        skipPageReset={skipPageReset}
      />
```

Comment: Can't you just use [`String.prototype.slice(0,3)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to keep the first 3 letters?

Comment: how can you show?? @Terry

Comment: Idk how EnhancedTable works but I suppose that in columns you can return a JSX element to show in the column, here you can make the `slice` as @Terry mentioned. Another solution its to do the slice on the data, e.g. `data.map(item => ({ ...item, lastName: lastName.slice(0,3) }))`